# Ion_Auth "from box" login error

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Should the login work as it is? I've puted files to my project, added sql but when I'm trying to log in at http://mysite.local/index.php/auth/login with default account (admin@admin.com/password) it gives me the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'group_id' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `email`, `id`, `password`, `group_id` FROM (`users`) WHERE
>   `email` = 'admin@admin.com' AND `active` = 1 LIMIT 1
>
> Filename: /home/kirill/WWW/hours/models/ion_auth_model.php
>
> Line Number: 593

Line num 593 is the last one over here.

```
        $query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column.', id, password, group_id')
              ->where($this->identity_column, $identity)
              ->where('active', 1)
              ->where($this->ion_auth->_extra_where)
              ->limit(1)
              ->get($this->tables['users']);
```

database.php configured with correct log in values and the tables are in place. Also Users table and users_groups have correct rows with admin login data.

If it really should work by default where to dig for a problem? I've tried to google this but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear, `Unknown column 'group_id' in 'field list'` means there are no columns named `group_id` in your `users` table.

Either create this column or don't select it.

Comment: It's really not. But it is in users_groups table and they using join to access both tables. I think this is the problem but I don't know how to find where exactly

Comment: There is no join in this query. Perhaps your code is outdated?

Comment: it seems to be : https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/ion_auth_model.php

Comment: It's really looks different here... I'll check this in 1 hr or so, thank you.

Comment: LOL, I've really used some outdated link to download the project. Thank's a lot it works now.